# What kind of function is this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this on a forum and I was wondering what it was. If I can get anybody's response it would be very appreciated.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Can you tell me what it does and what browsers support it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a function which constructs a [`FileSystemObject` in JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Microsoft's <strike>version</strike> implementation<sup>[citation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)</sup> of JavaScript). This sort of object provides access to a computer's file system.

ActiveX is only supported by Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Bakudan I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Matt Ball Which one is correct: JScript is Microsoft`s implementation or version of JavaScript?

Comment: @Bakudan what do you mean "version of JavaScript?" What do you mean by "correct?" (Side note: you don't have to "@user" if you're responding to the same person whose post you are commenting on. Post owners are automatically notified of comments on their posts.)

Comment: Ok, JScript is an implementation, not a version. I hope you are not angry about the edit. :)

Answer (score 3):

What it does is give access to your local filesystem on your PC. It is only supported by Internet Explorer.